# Fail to Create New Directory/File on automounted Windows drive

Tags: automount

My Windows drives were set to be automatically mounted in Ubuntu 8.10 when installed more than one year ago. Today I failed to creat a directory on one of the Windows drives, which rarely happened before:

`` $ mkdir /windows-d/tmp

mkdir: cannot create directory `/windows-d/tmp': Operation not supported ``

Same problem after switching to root. I can still read and modify the existing files on the Windows drive and but I am not able to create new directory or new file on it.

Permission info is here, for which I don't see anything wrong:

`$ ls -l / | grep "windows-d"

drwxrwxrwx   1 root root    229376 2010-10-09 17:47 windows-d`

Mounting information about the Windows drive is as follows:

`$ cat /etc/mtab

...

/dev/sda5 /windows-d fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0

...

$ cat /etc/fstab

# < file system > < mount point >   < type >  < options >   < dump >  < pass >

...

# Entry for /dev/sda5 :

UUID=BED8573DD856F35F /windows-d ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 1

...

$ df -h

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

...

/dev/sda5              32G   31G  1.2G  97% /windows-d`

I was wonder what's wrong?

Thanks and regards!

---

UPDATE:

I just rebooted my computer to Windows XP, created a new directory on the Windows drive then rebooted back to Ubuntu which now allow me to create new file and directory on the Windows drive. Simply rebooting to Windows without creating a new directory does not work. Does anyone know why?

Is there a way to solve the problem without rebooting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have ntfs drive and one can't be found from /etc/fstab (think you have typo, there is no ftab). Attleast one thing what point's out is "ntfs-3g", that is ntfs filesystem driver not filesystem itself.

And from /etc/mtab it's line is following:
/dev/sdb2 /media/ntfsHD vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush 0 0

edit: think this is not configuration ubuntu has created itself, is it? Usual mountpoin is /media/

Comment: You are right. Already corrected the typo.

Comment: Am I right that the line in /etc/mtab shows that your drive is vfat not ntfs? What do dmask and umask mean in mtab and fstab?

Comment: To your question in edit: it was set up during installation of Ubuntu, when I specified to automount the Windows drives every time  Ubuntu is started.

Comment: You are correft, it were actually fat32 (checked with gparted-programm). 
What comes to issue being fixed with boot to windows, i believe, that ould cause this for some reason, that disk were marked as "reserved" and witch windows overrun and fixed. Can be caused sometimes with bad shutdown of windows. Tho there should be warning about that.

Comment: If above is not the case you should try to mount that disk with mount command after removing everything related to that partition in /etc/fstab and mtab (take backups). If it works out set-up new line to fstab for it.

Comment: Thanks!I haven't used Windows for quite a while and the operation worked fine many times before the failure came in in the middle of the same running of Ubuntu. May I ask how to remove everything related to that partition in /etc/fstab and mtab (take backups)? What is the new line for fstab? What options are used to mount the Windows drive?